# Con expresiones regulares imprimir palabras con determinadas características. Python

Tags: python, regex

Necesito imprimir de un archivo las palabras que comienzan con un número y finalizan con un punto.

He intentado lo siguiente y no me devuelve nada:

```
import re

archivo = open("news.txt", encoding= "cp1252")

for line in archivo:

    line= line.rstrip()
    if re.search("^[0-9]+\.$", line):
        print(line)
```

Ahora, si quito .$ me imprime solo la primer parte de la condición.
Entiendo que es algún problema en la sintaxis de la expresión regular pero no logro darme cuenta.

Comment: Entre los números y el punto puede haber otros caracteres (como letras)? Podrías poner ejemplos de las palabras que tenes y el resultado que buscás?

Comment: Si, puede haber otros caracteres. El texto es un poco largo, pero estas serían las palabras que busco:        
4 hours ago.
1 day ago.
23 minutes ago.
4 hours ago
6 hours ago.
3 hours ago.
1 hour ago.
1 hour ago.
2 hours ago.
4 hours ago

Comment: Cuando hagas una pregunta agrega este tipo de información, así es más fácil que te respondan.

Comment: Gracias! Lo voy a tomar en cuenta!!

Answer (score 1):

Con la expresión que estás usando `^[0-9]+\.$` lo que haces es mirar si la palabra empieza con números y termina con un punto, pero no estás mirando que es lo que pasa entre los números y el punto.

Por eso este string **3 hours ago.** nunca se imprime, pero éste **3.** sí se imprime.

---

#### Una Solución:

Podrías usar algo así:
`^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z\s]*\.$`

---

#### Explicación de `[a-zA-Z\s]*`

- El cuantificador `*` matchea entre cero a n veces.
- a-z: una letra **minúscula** entre a y z.
- A-Z: una letra **mayúscula** entre A y Z.
- \s: Cualquier espacio presente.

Si no le agregas el cuantificador `*` te va a devolver palabras que tengan una sola letra o espacio entre el número y el punto. Con el cuantificador puede haber cero o n letras y/o espacios entre el número y el punto.

Te recomiendo ésta página para jugar un poco con **regex**: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Me super ayudaste!! mil gracias y también por la recomendación!

Comment: @m_noui La forma de agradecer una respuesta aqui es darle +1 y aceptarla :-)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con:

```
for cadena in lista:
if re.match(r'^\d{1}\w*\.$', cadena):
    print(cadena)
```

Donde `^\d{1}` indica que encuentre un dígito al inicio, `\w*` indica que después tiene que contener cero o varios caracteres alfanuméricos.

Luego tiene que estar seguido de un punto `.$` hasta el final.